# Regex performance issue on a really big string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Right now I am new to using regexes so I would really appreciate your help.

I have a really large string (I am parsing an as3 file to json) and I need to locate for those trailing commas out there in the objects..

This is the regex I am using

```
public static string TrimTraillingCommas(string jsonCode)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"(.*?),\s*(\}|\])", (RegexOptions.Multiline));

    return regex.Replace(jsonCode, m => String.Format("{0} {1}", m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value));
}
```

The problem with it is that it's really slow. Without using it in the string the time to complete the program is : `00:00:00.0289668` and with it :  `00:00:00.4096293`

Could someone suggest a improved regex or algorithm for faster replacing those trailing commas.

[Here is where i start from ( the string with the trailing commas )](http://pastebin.com/xZqFbu4Q)

[Here is the end string I need](http://pastebin.com/kTfzFc6g)

Comment: What do you get if you compile it? With: `RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline`

Comment: Instead of declaring a new `Regex` each time you call `TrimTraillingCommas`, you could declare it as static.  Otherwise the regex needs to be "compiled" each time at runtime.  Regardless of how complex the regex is

Comment: Wait, why are there trailing commas in the first place? If this was [valid json](http://json.org/), there shouldn't be any, right? Maybe you could eliminate the need for RegEx entirely if you had valid json.

Comment: @null The point is i don't have a valid json. I don't even have a json .. I have a bunch of as3 files that are written with many mistakes and I need to parse they're values into valid json files.

Comment: @JordanKanchelov what do you mean with "mistakes", do they compile?

Comment: @null They do ,because the as3 compiler ignore such kind of things, but I think we all agree that it ain't a good thing to leave trailing commas and such things even if you can. Right now , because is very specific to parse them from .net , it feels like pain with all those exceptions I need to catch while reading the files and trying to convert them to json object.

Comment: @JordanKanchelov it might be easier to create valid  json files instead of going through that hell. Are these As3 files classes? Could you upload one?

Comment: @null  I know its a lot easier ,but i don't have choice. Its too long to explain how it happened to go from as3 file to parse it with .net to json .. And about the upload I shouldn't or at least i have to obfuscate a bit the variables and things, because of my coworkers .. :) If you are interested I could on pm or something

Comment: No, I'm not interested in helping you if you are not willing to explain your requirements. (-1)

Comment: @null: The OP has clearly explained their immediate requirements. I appreciate that you might be trying to address the underlying problem, but it's up to them to decide whether they want to go down this route. Either way, it didn't merit a downvote.

Comment: @Douglas but the attitude did.

Comment: AM I blind? I don't see any difference between the two strings

Comment: @MikeMB in this showed case [this is the difference](http://s7.postimg.org/3k3m3znzt/Capture.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your regular expression by eliminating your capture groups, replacing the purpose of the latter one by a lookahead:

```
var regex = new Regex(@",\s*(?=\}|\])");
return regex.Replace(jsonCode, " ");
```

Comment: This was exactly what i needed :). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the first expression `.*?` and you can convert the alternation
into a character class. That's about the best you could do.

```
var regex = new Regex(@",[^\S\r\n]*([}\]])");
return regex.Replace(jsonCode, " $1");
```